# WebApi OData HttpConfiguration Extension methods missing

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, odata

OData v4 HttpConfiguration Extension methods seem to be missing for me. Here's my Register method for the Web API:

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Use camel case for JSON data.
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.EnableCaseInsensitive();

        config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);            
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "api", OdataConfig.GetEdm());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );

    }
}
```

Methods like `EnableCaseInsensitive()` and `EnableEnumPrefixFree()` are completely missing from System.Web.Odata(.Extensions).

They are present in the [documentation](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#06-01-custom-url-parsing), and in the [source code](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/Extensions/HttpConfigurationExtensions.cs#L35) for the assembly, but when exploring the assembly I've got, they're flat out missing:

[image: missing extensions screenshot]

I've attempted to reinstall OData from Nuget several times - I can't seem to find anyone else with this issue. About ready to pull out my hair. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaaaand right after I post here, I figure it out. By downgrading the Nuget package to 5.9.1 I end up getting the missing pieces.

Answer (score 3):

I think downgrade is not a good solution :D

The API has been changed to dependency injection: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#13-04-DependencyInjection

You have to do the following:
(Example)

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // OData
    config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);

    config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", BuildRoute);
}

private static void BuildRoute(IContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder
        .AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => GetEdmModel())
        .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault())
        .AddService<ODataUriResolver>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => new CaseInsensitiveODataUriResolver());
}
```

My Resolver class looks as follows:

```
public class CaseInsensitiveODataUriResolver : UnqualifiedODataUriResolver
{
    public override bool EnableCaseInsensitive
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }

        set
        {
        }
    }
}
```

You can derive from `ODataUriResolver`, `UnqualifiedODataUriResolver` or `StringAsEnumResolver`.

It's not possible to write something like

```
s => new ODataUriResolver { EnableCaseInsensitive = true }
```

Please see also
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/812
and 
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/853

Comment: This is a better answer than the OP's own self-accepted answer.

Comment: This may be a better answer for the community, but it wasn't for me - this is one of the things I tried that didn't actually work. (It was long ago, so I don't remember the actual reason)